# Configure a Windows PC as network appliance w/o monitor, keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows, networking, appliance

I intend to use a small form factor PC with Windows 7 Professional installed as a network appliance attached directly to my customer's LAN without connecting a monitor, keyboard or mouse.

How should I configure the networking for my PC so that I can access it via say my laptop?

I figure that I can do it 2 ways.

1. Attach my laptop to the PC using a crossover cable? Connect via RDP and configure networking.
2. Configure an IP address on the PC before I deliver it to the customer place.  At the customer's place, attach the PC to LAN and connect to the IP address which I previously configured from my laptop or from one of the customer's workstations.

I know the first way is doable, but is the second way possible? I'm sorry if this question sounds ridiculous - I am Delphi programmer but a novice on networking.

Finally, if possible, I hope to make the configuration process web based as I wouldn't like to reveal the fact that I am using Win7 Pro for the network appliance!

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to Delphi or even programming.

Comment: Boot without keyboard? It's impossible, AFAIK

Comment: @Lazy Badger, why is that impossible? It is very common for machines to be able to boot without keyboards, take a look at server farms for example. They all boot without input devices and all have remote access or a terminal that rolls around and plugs in when needed.

Comment: @MaQleod - I figure out that this is possible for new systems - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/c98a1b82-db6c-4cab-8a67-d4a4ccad17e2

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of tools that might help you out:

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/): Allows you to remotely access a PC over the net.

[image: TeamViewer screen shot]

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/): Lets you share your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers on your desk.  This won't share a monitor, but it's a good tool to have in your toolbox.

[image: Image from Synergy site]

Answer (score 1):

Two additional options:

- Bring a small keyboard/mouse/display with you for the initial setup
- Request an IP you can use from the customer before installation, and configure it to use that IP in advance

Comment: The 2nd idea is good.  I was thinking of attached the PC to my laptop using a cross cable and configure it using that method, do you think this is feasible?

Comment: @ Joel - we can access most router devices via a fixed IP address out from the box using a crossover cable, do you know how this is done?  Are they running a DHCP server or something like that?  Thanks.